# Compiling mutiple files from command line in Java

Tags: java, class, cmd

I am a beginner in Java and I've built a class "Employee" and a test program "EmployeeTest". From the command line, I have typed javac *.java.
It compiled both files and created Employee.class and EmployeeTest.class.
How do I run those now?

Thanks so much

Comment: If you're a beginner, consider installing an IDE, like Netbeans. Working from the command line is just a pain.

Comment: You could, of course, read the Java Tutorial. [Lesson: The "Hello World!" Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) give complete instructions on wrting/compiling/running your first Java program using Netabeans or  using the Windows/Unix command lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Employee.class and EmployeeTest.class are in the same directory, and both do not specify package (they use default package) and EmployeeTest.class contains the main method...you can use this:

```
java EmployeeTest
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install an IDE which contain a compiler, interpreter, or both, such as NetBeans and Eclipse.

You will be able to run and compile your code easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application using the `java <Classname>` command. Replace the class name property with your own, e.g. `EmployeeTest`. If you are having problems, watch your case, since the class name is case sensitive. Also omit the `.java` file extension, Java needs to know the class name here.

So in your case, try running this from the command line:

```
java EmployeeTest
```